# Aerobic exercise: Any updates or comments to the Cooper method?

Tags: running

I read a book published in the 80s (by Kenneth Cooper, MD), Aerobics, in which Dr. Cooper suggests a way of getting fit without risking one's cardiovascular health. He devised a point system of exercise based on one's fitness level (initially determined by how much distance one can run in 12min, Cooper's 12-min test) and one's choice of exercise (walking, running, swimming, etc.). For those in the first level (not fit), for example, he set a 16-week program to get fit in a "safe" way. His system was based on his studies participated in by the US Armed Forces so it looked like his system had some "clinical" basis.

Would any of you have come across exercise programs based on similar observations with a large group of people?  I am particularly interested in running or walking, so perhaps studies related to these would help me improve my aerobic fitness.

Comment: What is your goal? Improving your aerobic fitness?

Comment: Note that StackExchange isn't a discussion board but a Q&A site. In the current form the question is far too vague to be reasonably answered. Please edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: Voted to close, but check out Galloway Run/Walk.

Comment: Basically, you don't care about Cooper, you just want a recommendation on how to get in shape. Fine, so why not just ask that? Also I suspect this question has already been answered in several ways, so perhaps you should explore our running tag

Comment: @Informaficker I agree... but can anybody recommend a good discussion board?

Comment: @TonnyMadsen I think you should ask that either in [meta] or [chat].